# Correct using of notifydatasetchanged

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application which contains a listview with some article but I have confusion with using of notifyDataSetChanged().

My confusion derived from insert operation because I want add a new item to listview from dialog. The "problem" is on add button click of dialog: I create a new Product item and add to productsList then call notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh listview, but I could not call it because my listview is updated anyway and I not understand if it is correct or not also because if I not use dialog to add, without notify method listview doesn't refresh.

I did some research and all of them use notify method.

Below the code that I use in my Fragment:

```
productsList = new ArrayList<>();
mAdapter = new products_list_adapter(getActivity(), productsList);

        asyncProducts = new GetProductsAsyncTasks(getActivity(), productsList, listViewProducts);
        asyncProducts.execute();

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        btnAggiungiProdotto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.setTitle("Add");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1000);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);

                Button btnConferma = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnConferma);
                btnConferma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText txtDescr = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtDescrizione);
                        EditText txtBarcode = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtBarocode);
                        Product p = new Product();
                        p.SetDescription(txtDescr.getText().toString());
                        p.SetBarCode(txtBarcode.getText().toString());

                       productsList.add(p);
                       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        dialog.dismiss();

                   }
                });
```

I would know this behaviour is correct or not.

Comment: You always want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you're modifying the dataset yourself directly. In this particular case, it sounds like the `Dialog` is causing a full refresh on the `ListView` anyway, so it just happens to work if you omit that call there, but don't ever rely on that behavior. Just always call `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you're supposed to.

Comment: Thx for your reply. About the behaviour of dialog and refreshing of listview are you sure or is it your idea?

Comment: That's likely what's happening, since the `Activity` has to redraw when `Dialog` is dismissed. It's kind of irrelevant what's actually causing it, though, 'cause you shouldn't be omitting the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call anyway.

Comment: I undestand. Thank you!